# 2 Rspec tests fail due to nil:NillCLass error in model spec when others pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following Rspec test for a vote model, which includes a custom validation ensuring you can't vote on your own content, which is shown below. I am puzzled as to why only 2 of these tests fail with a nilclass error when the other tests within the spec pass.

@vote must be nil but why aren't the other tests failing with the same error?

vote.rb

```
validates :ensure_not_author

def ensure_not_author 
    votable = self.votable_type.downcase
    errors.add(:user_id, "You can't vote on your own content.") if self.votable.user_id == self.user_id
  end
```

factories

```
factory :answer do
    user_id :user
    question_id :question
    body "you need to change your grip"
    votes_count 0
    correct false
  end

  factory :vote do
    user_id :user
    votable_id :answer
    votable_type "Answer"
    value 1
    points 5
  end

factory :user do |u|
    u.sequence(:email) {|n| "test#{n}@hotmail.com"}
    u.sequence(:username) {|n| "tester#{n}" }
    u.password "password"
    u.password_confirmation "password" 
    u.remember_me true
    u.reputation 200
  end
```

vote_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Vote do
  before(:each) do
    @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @answer = FactoryGirl.create(:answer, user_id: @user)
    @vote = Vote.create(user_id: @user2.id, value: 1, points: 5, votable_id: @answer.id, votable_type: "Answer")
  end

  subject { @vote }

  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:votable_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:votable_type) }
  it { should respond_to(:value) }
  it { should respond_to(:points) }

   describe 'value' do
     before { @vote.value = nil }
     it { should_not be_valid }
   end

   describe "user_id" do
      before { @vote.user_id = nil }
       it { should_not be_valid }
     end

   describe "votable_id" do
     before { @vote.votable_id = nil }
     it { should_not be_valid }
   end

   describe "votable type" do
      before { @vote.votable_type = nil }
      it { should_not be_valid }
   end

   describe "vote value" do
      before { @vote.value = 5 }
      it { should_not be_valid }
   end
end
```

Failures:

```
1) Vote votable_id 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/vote.rb:17:in `ensure_not_author'
     # ./spec/models/vote_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Vote votable type 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/vote.rb:16:in `ensure_not_author'
     # ./spec/models/vote_spec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You validator `ensure_not_author` depends `Vote#votable_type` and `Vote#votable` to function well. And when you test validity of `@vote`, this validator will be tested.

However, in your `"votable_id"` testcase, you set `votable_id` to be `nil`. Later when you test `@vote`'s validity with `should_not be_valid`, the `ensure_not_author` is called and failed at `self.votable.user_id` because ActiveRecord will query for `Votable` with `votable_id`.

Similarly, your `"votable type"` test case failed at `self.votable_type.downcase` since you set `votable_type` to be `nil`.

You should check the availability of the attributes in your validator before you send messages to them. Or write other validators to check them before `ensure_not_author`.